# Dropdown menu stays blocked

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have problems with a dropdown menu, it does not retract back, but just on a single page, the contact page, where I have a Google map. It's blocked like this:

[image: dropdown]

I tried working in the CSS, but with no result. What am I missing?
I hope it's enough info; I'll post more if needed.

This is the HTML code

```
<nav id=\"topmenu\" class=\"clearfix\">            
  <ul class=\"dropdown\">    
    <li class=\"menu-level-0 current-menu-ancestor\">
      <a href=\"index.php\"><span>Acasa</span></a>
    </li>     
    <li class=\"menu-level-0 current-menu-ancestor\">
      <a href=\"desprenoi.php\"><span>Despre noi</span></a>
    </li>                       
    <li class=\"menu-level-0 current-menu-ancestor\">
      <a href=\"piese.php\"><span>Piese auto</span></a>
    </li>                       
    <li class=\"menu-level-0 mega-nav\">
      <a href=\"#\"><span>Servicii</span></a>

      <ul class=\"submenu-1\">
        <li class=\"menu-level-1\">

          <ul class=\"submenu-2\">                                
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"mecanica.php\"><span>Mecanica auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"electrica.php\"><span>Electrica auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"tinichigerie.php\"><span>Tinichigerie auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"vopsitorie.php\"><span>Vopsitorie auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"diagnoza.php\"><span>Diagnoza auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"blog.html\"><span>Vulcanizare auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"tractari.php\"><span>Tractari auto</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class=\"menu-level-2\">
              <a href=\"itp.php\"><span>ITP</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>                                                                                               
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class=\"menu-level-0 current-menu-ancestor\">
      <a href=\"foto.php\"><span>Galerie Foto</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class=\"menu-level-0\">
      <a href=\"contact.php\"><span>Patrascu Emil: 0745 374 793</span></a>
    </li>                                                               
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

The dropdown is on submenu-1.

The CSS: http://pastebin.com/1g74fqW1

The contact page

```
<div class="body_wrap">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>      
  <div id="menuu">
    <form action="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps" method="get">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cum ajung aici?" id="submit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="45.1615909, 24.6700443" />
      <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Trimite un mesaj!" onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)" id="submit"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css of Contact page

```
#menuu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index:99;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 600px;
}
```

Live page: http://serviciiregie.com/contact.php

Comment: It might be easier to debug if you provide a live example. I would suggest either recreating the issue in jsfiddle or a similar service; or provide a link to the live site.

Comment: http://www.filehost.ro/31636679/Page_rar/
I've uploaded the page saved from opera, it reproduces exactly!

Comment: If you provide a way for users to view a live representation of the issue you are more likely to receive help.

Comment: Problem is that the site is on localhost and I'm in a campus with blocked ports, so it's impossible, but I'll try something!

Comment: I'd suggest just recreating it in jsfiddle. Also, many times trying to recreate an issue will help you see what is causing it.

Comment: For the moment I've put the site online: http://serviciiregie.com/contact.php
Not familiar with Fiddler but I'll try.

Comment: No. Use a site such as (the repeatedly suggested) [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/)... Or just use Stack Overflow's 'Snippet' feature (click the `< >` button in the editor (to open the editor, click the [edit] link)). Hosting the demo on your, or any other, live site limits the use, since we can't rely on it being kept there once the problem is fixed and we can't easily see or fix the code in place without copying it elsewhere - which means you've done more work to make things more awkward.

Comment: I'll get it on Fiddler, sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This page loads jquery three separate times:

- 1.8.3 from js/libs/jquery.min.js, in `<head>`
- 1.11.0 from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js, just after the google maps api
- 1.4.2 from http://code.jquery.com, just after the `<script>` block labeled “The following example creates a marker in Stockholm”.

You’re also using the jquery easing plugin. When the menu pops up, the page gets a “`TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function`”, which is probably breaking whatever’s meant to hide the menu.

One of the extra jquery versions (I’m looking at *you*, 1.4.2) is probably incompatible with the easing plugin. Try taking it out!